# Spatie laravel/permission - Modifying table and methods

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

I'm working with Laravel 5.6 and Spatie [laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) and I want to modify the `model_has_roles` so it can have an extra field named `code`.

Now, i did that thing by modifying the migrations the library provides via the next command:

`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider" --tag="migrations"`

This library provides a useful command:

`$user->assignRole($role);`

That lets me assign a role to an user within a single line of code. My problem is that, using this command will throw an error because i can't leave the `code` field empty. Either way, i can't do something like this:

`$user->assignRole($role, ['code' => '0001']`);

Because it will say that `0001 is not a role`. Basically, it asumes that i'm trying to assign TWO different roles to the user: `$role` and `0001` while actually i'm trying to assign a single role: `$role` with an extra parameter for the table `model_has_roles`.

Is there a way to archieve such a thing? I thought that maybe i could modify the logic behind the `assignRole` method but i don't know how to extend/edit the library methods.

Comment: You don't give us enough info about how you dealing with the new column called `code` but you can set it as nullable and its default value to `null`. if this is what you asking about I'll write it as answer

Comment: I said that i can't set the `code` value for my user/role relationship while using the `assignRole` method. I don't want the `code` to be `null` by default: I want to assign a role AND set an extra field to the `model_has_roles` table while doing it.

Comment: I think that's done in two steps unless you making a change in **assignRole** method

Comment: But, how can i change the `assignRole` method or what are those two steps like?

Answer (score 1):

I see you have already added the column in the migration so now you need to make the changes in the **assignRole** method.

**Spatie permission** package works by adding the **HasRoles** trait in the **User** model class.

This is the full path of the trait-

```
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
```

To achieve what you desire with the **assignRole** method, you can simply copy the content from **HasRoles** trait and then create your own trait from this code. You can see the method in this trait-

```
    public function assignRole(...$roles)
    {
        $roles = collect($roles)
            ->flatten()
            ->map(function ($role) {
                if (empty($role)) {
                    return false;
                }

                return $this->getStoredRole($role);
            })
            ->filter(function ($role) {
                return $role instanceof Role;
            })
            ->each(function ($role) {
                $this->ensureModelSharesGuard($role);
            })
            ->map->id
            ->all();

        $model = $this->getModel();

        if ($model->exists) {
            $this->roles()->sync($roles, false);
            $model->load('roles');
        } else {
            $class = \get_class($model);

            $class::saved(
                function ($object) use ($roles, $model) {
                    static $modelLastFiredOn;
                    if ($modelLastFiredOn !== null && $modelLastFiredOn === $model) {
                        return;
                    }
                    $object->roles()->sync($roles, false);
                    $object->load('roles');
                    $modelLastFiredOn = $object;
                });
        }

        $this->forgetCachedPermissions();

        return $this;
    }
```

Make your desired changes in this method and use your **custom** trait rather than using the spatie's **HasRole** trait.

Alternatively, you can also override the method from **HasRoles** trait in your class which is an easier and preferred way.